# Loop through a list of substrings in Groovy script

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to create a Jenkins pipeline using Groovy script to call a Ansible playbook. I need to pass several variable and value pairs to the ansible playbook. I use a function to call the playbook, and the Groovy looks like this:

```
void RunAnsiblePlaybook(String playbookPath, String playbookParam = '') {

         for (item in playbookParam) {
             extras += " -e ${item}"
         } 
         ansiblePlaybook become: true,
                         colorized: true,
                         extras: extras,
                         installation: 'ansible',
                         vaultCredentialsId: 'AnsibleVaultPassword',
                         playbook: playbookPath
}

pipeline {
    agent any

    stage('Get prod copy') {
    steps { 
        script {
                RunAnsiblePlaybook("",
                                "jenkins/ansible_playbooks/try.yml",
                                "['source_instance=${env.SOURCE_INSTANCE}','source_instance=${env.TARGET_INSTANCE}','specific_snapshot_name=${A_SPECIFIC_SNAPSHOT_NAME}']")
}
```

Variable `SOURCE_INSTANCE`, `TARGET_INSTANCE`, and `A_SPECIFIC_SNAPSHOT_NAME` are defined in the pipeline.

I was hoping the RunAnsiblePlaybook function will pass `-e source_instance=apple -e source_instance=orange -e specific_snapshot_name=berry` to the playbook, but instead, this is what I see from the output:

```
11:58:18  [test_grovvy_script] $ ansible-playbook _new/google/ansible/ansible-root/playbooks/utility/prodcopy/dry.yml -b --become-user root --vault-password-file /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/_migration_jobs/test_ppc/vault6368263148356134694.password --private-key=**** -vvv
 -e [ -e " -e s -e o -e u -e r -e c -e e -e _ -e i -e n -e s -e t -e a -e n -e c -e e -e = -e a -e p -e p -e l -e e " -e , -e " -e t -e a -e r -e g -e e -e t -e _ -e i -e n -e s -e t -e a -e n -e c -e e -e = -e o -e r -e a -e n -e g -e e ............]
```

It picked up each letter as an item.

How I can make it to pick up `-e source_instance=apple -e source_instance=orange -e specific_snapshot_name=berry` ?

Thanks,
Philip

Answer (score 1):

That looks expected as your `playbookParam` is a `String`. Since it's Groovy, I think you can actually omit the type, or use a `List`.

But generally I would advise against using Groovy wrappers and suggest to use `sh` pipeline steps, [inventories](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html), and [Ansible environment variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html) (wherever possible) to reduce the complexity and keep the execution string as short and understandable as possible. You can also [pass the extra vars from files](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#vars-from-a-json-or-yaml-file), or use [`env` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/env_lookup.html) to fetch the variable values from the environment variables.

Comment: Using list is working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change your function and code like below.

```
// Function call
RunAnsiblePlaybook("jenkins/ansible_playbooks/try.yml",["source_instance=${env.SOURCE_INSTANCE}","source_instance=${env.TARGET_INSTANCE}","specific_snapshot_name=${A_SPECIFIC_SNAPSHOT_NAME}"])
```

```
// Function
void RunAnsiblePlaybook(String playbookPath, def playbookParam) {
    
     for (item in playbookParam) {
         extras += " -e ${item}"
     } 
     ansiblePlaybook become: true,
                     colorized: true,
                     extras: extras,
                     installation: 'ansible',
                     vaultCredentialsId: 'AnsibleVaultPassword',
                     playbook: playbookPath
}
```